# MVC 5 Cascading Data

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, partial-views, html-helper

I am working on an MVC 5 razor page (using Entity Framework 6) that will display Vendor information. Each vendor can have multiple classes, and each class can have multiple subclasses. What I want to do is display the vendor information at the top, show the list of classes below that info, and then have a third section with a list of subclasses for the selected class. My question is what is the best way to do this?

Currently I am trying to do it with the main page getting passed a model of type vendor, and then within that page, displaying two partial views via @Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", value). I can pass the class list partial view the ID of the vendor when the page loads without issue, the real problem is figuring out how to pass the selected ID of a class to the partial view for subclass. I've tried using hidden fields, but I'm not sure how to pass the html.Action the value of the hidden field.

This is my first MVC application, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is you model fully populated (each class and subclass) when you pass the model to the view? And is the view for editing data (i.e. a form)?

Comment: The Model passed to the view contains a Vendor object. and since I'm using entity framework, the vendor object has a vendor.VendorClasses property that would allow me to do a foreach loop through the classes. However, the vendor object knows nothing of its sublasses. And yes, ideally the view will allow the users to update the vendor information and add/remove classes and subclass.

Comment: If your editing, using a partial is not the best option since it will not (by default) render you controls correctly. It would be better to either use a `for` loop in the main view or use custom `EditorTemplates`. Can you post your models for `Vendor` and its sub classes

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are saying that you are using partial views with `@Html.Action()` helper - this is not for a partial view, but rather to produce a link to navigate to another page...That being said, I think I know what you want to do.

Second off, you need to post more code to show you made an attempt - stack overflow is not a source of free development consulting work. I think I know what you are trying to do, but even posting some sort of UI mockup might make a general discussion easier. That being said, I won't give you any code in the answer, just a general idea of how I would approach the problem.

To start,  you should have a dedicated controller for Vendor, VendorClasses, and whatever the third subclass is (I'm going to assume its called VendorSubClass for the sake of example) since you chose the MVC pattern.

Next comes the part about displaying all of the information on a single page. The only place I could potentially see it making sense to show all of that info is on the views for VendorSubClass (however only VendorSubClass properties should be editable here) and even then, it might just make sense to have really informative breadcrumbs instead.

You would need to pass an object to the view that contained the VendorSubClass, its parent VendorClass, and its grandparent Vendor information. If you're using entity framework, this is a snap (but you didn't say you were so I'm making my explanation more generic). Then, you can reference partial views by using the helpers:

```
@Html.Partial('VendorPartial', Model.Vendor) 
@Html.Partial('VendorClassPartial', Model.VendorClass)
```

as you can see above, I am not passing IDs - but rather the actual properties(objects) themselves which the partial views will use to render the details. This overview should get you started and give you some stuff to google.